# How to launch html file (with css and js files included) on remote server on node.js with angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, static-files

I started working with Angular 2 and have one issue.
I compiled my app for production through "ng build" and got an index.html and other files like js and css in this folder.
I need to publics them on web

- Im using remote ubuntu on digital ocean.
  I found [this nice script](https://gist.github.com/hectorcorrea/2573391), which solved a problem, but to enter a project I need to print in a browser a path like this: somehost:8080/index.html.

Can you help please and explain please, how I can use a path like somehost:8080, or just somehost:8080/index, but without a file extension? I found of course, even simpler scripts, but they dont serve js and css, which are included.

And next question, actually main, is this decision the most elegant to provide an entrance to the app, or there is a better and smarter way? Afterwards, Im thinking about PM2, because all that I need is to launch it like a linux service and to reload the app, if it will be crashed.

Thanks!

Comment: I would just use nginx. It's a bit more complicated though

Comment: Thanks, but its another . Here its kind of problem with routing, as I understood well.  There is a browser url input field Is it working like this?